# Unwanted paragraph when saving html in DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

After manipulations with DOM element and saving it using `$dom->saveHTML();` getting extra empty paragraph in my output, here is my code:

PHP:

```
$dom_str = "Phasellus eu arcu vest, <mark data-tooltip='tooltip'></mark> sodales dui."
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($dom_str);
$dom_items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('mark'); // retrieving elements by tag

$dom_app = $dom->createElement('amp-script');
$dom_span = $dom->createElement('span');

$dom_app->appendChild($dom_span);

$mark_item = $dom_items->item(0);
$mark_item->appendChild($dom_app); // appending additional HTML
$output_dom = $dom->saveHTML(); // saving DOM       

$output .= '<div><p>'. $output_dom .'</p></div>';

return $output;
```

Output:

```
<div>
<p></p> <! –– Unwanted paragraph ––>
<p>Phasellus eu arcu vest, <mark><amp-script><span></span></amp-script></mark> sodales dui</p>
</div>
```

Already tried `$dom->loadHTML($dom_str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);` but empty paragraph still stays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `loadHTML` with a partial HTML snippet instead of a full HTML document, it is probably a good idea to pass both `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` and `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` OR'd together as the second parameter, otherwise `DOMDocument` is going to start "fixing" things for you:

```php
$dom->loadHTML($dom_str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

I also had to add `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` to get the `mark` tag to work

With those two changes, and ignoring your string concatenation at the end, I get this:

```php
$dom_str = "Phasellus eu arcu vest, <mark data-tooltip='tooltip'></mark> sodales dui.";
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // Enabled HTML5 tags
$dom->loadHTML($dom_str, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD); // Don't automatically create html/body/doctype tags
$dom_items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('mark'); // retrieving elements by tag

$dom_app = $dom->createElement('amp-script');
$dom_span = $dom->createElement('span');

$dom_app->appendChild($dom_span);

$mark_item = $dom_items->item(0);
$mark_item->appendChild($dom_app); // appending additional HTML
echo $dom->saveHTML(); // saving DOM
```

This outputs the following:

```
<p>Phasellus eu arcu vest, <mark data-tooltip="tooltip"><amp-script><span></span></amp-script></mark> sodales dui.</p>
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/KRDKS

Comment: Hm, something weird is happening, your Demo works fine but my code still don't. Maybe the problem is because this is a shortcode function? `$dom_str = $attributes["description_text"];` I 'm getting that string from wordpress shortcode attribute.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit confused, in Demo attached there is no string concatenation with `div` and `p` but output wrapped in `p`;

Comment: The only solution for now is to remove all paragraphs with `str_replace` `$output_dom = str_replace(['<p>','</p>'],['',''], $dom->saveHTML());`

Comment: When you load content using `loadHTML()`, if any of the text _isn't_ wrapped in a tag already it is assumed to be in a `<p>` tag, and one is made for you. If you wrap all of this in a function (which I think you did originally, you just didn't post the everything), you can ignore WordPress/shortcodes completely and just think about data in and data out. If you build it this way, your shortcode logic can call this helper function but this function stays pure PHP, unaware of WordPresss, which makes it easier to debug.

Comment: Ok, got it =) So I'll just load HTML string which is already wrapped in desired tag. Like this for example: `$dom_str = '<p>' . $attributes["description_text"] . '</p>';` Thanks for your time @ChrisHaas

Comment: @la_petite_kozel if the original content have p tag, then after using this, the p tag gone...